# Serialization and Deserialization of JodaTime dates as json

Tags: java, json, jackson, jodatime, jackson-modules

According to the documentation found here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda

the following code snippet should pass

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());

final String INPUT_JSON = "{\"start\" : \"1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z\"}";
Bean bean = mapper.readValue(INPUT_JSON, Bean.class);
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
Assert.assertEquals(INPUT_JSON, json);
```

However, this instead returns:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :{"start" : "1972-12-28T12:00:01.000Z"}
Actual   :{"start":94392001000}
```

Here is the pom file i'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Why isn't the datetime object not serialized correctly?

Comment: I guess you are defining a Bean class: `public class Bean {
  public DateTime start;
}`. Don't you?

Comment: Yes i am, seems i found the issue. Documentation doesnt state that         WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS  needs to be set to false. it's default set to true.

Comment: Glad you found it. You can accept your own answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test seems to be missing this feature.

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS ,false);
```